# Returning a pointer messes up the object (access violation)

Tags: c++, pointers, access-violation, assimp

I'm fiddling around with assimp and C++, and I wrote a simple function to load a scene from a file. However, when I try to return the pointer, the object gets messed up and I get access violation if I try to retrieve member data. This snippet should demonstrate the case:

```
const aiScene* ResManager::loadScene(const std::string& pFile)
{
    Assimp::Importer importer;
    const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile(pFile, aiProcessPreset_TargetRealtime_MaxQuality);
    if(!scene)
    {
        printf("%s\n", importer.GetErrorString());
        return 0;
    }

    // If I break the debug here, 'scene' is valid
    return scene;
}

void ResManager::loadFromFile(const std::string& pFile)
{
    const aiScene* scn = loadScene(pFile);
    // If I break the debug here, 'scn' contains gibberish
}
```

I think I've missed something essential here about pointers and consts and such. Any ideas?

Comment: Is any part of scene held by the importer? Because that goes out of scope.

Comment: Could be something happening during the destruction of `importer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems `importer` destructs when the function ends and therefore the object `scene` does not point to a valid pointer anymore.
I think that dynamically allocating `importer` with

```
   Assimp::Importer *importer = new Assimp::Importer;
```

should do the trick.

You should later on destroy this object with

`delete importer;`

Comment: Ah, this solved it! Do I need to somehow worry about destroying 'importer' later on, though?

Comment: Okay, good to know. :) And I will, as soon as it lets me to do so. :p